# Transferring variables between forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms - Form1 and Form2.

Form1:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void Drawnewmap(bool suzey) {
            bool dsuzey=suzey;
            if (dsuzey==true) textBox1.Text = "1" ;

        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     }
```

Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    bool m = false;
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true) m = true;
    f1.Drawnewmap(m);
    this.Close();
}
```

but when I click, nothing happens. TextBox is empty. Why?

Comment: FYI - You don't have to the `== true` in the conditionals. You can just say `if (checkBox1.Checked) m = true;`. The same for `if (dusuzey) textBox1.Text = "1";`. This would force you to name the variables such that it is immediately obvious why they are `true` or `false`, like `bool is_box_checked; .. if(is_box_checked) {..}`.

Comment: @ja72: It should read more like a predicate than a question: `box_is_checked`, thus: `if (box_is_checked) ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because You create new Form1 instance. And I think that is bad idea to call something from parent window in child Window. But you can do smoething like that:
When you create Form2, pass reference to current Form1 object

```
Form2 form = new Form2(this);
```

In Form2 constructor save Form1 reference in private variable.

```
private Form1 myform1;
```

Then your code need to look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool m = false;
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true) m = true;
    myform1.Drawnewmap(m);
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never actually show the form, perhaps you should have something more like:

I have 2 forms - Form1 and Form2.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    bool m = false;
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true) m = true;
    f1.Drawnewmap(m);
    f1.Show(); // You're missing this call
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reach your first active form via your second form, you should define the first form in your second form like:

```
Form1 frm = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
```

instead of

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

Since you will create a new form if you use "Form1 f1 = new Form1();", you will not reach the active form.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the `form1` you created.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    bool m = false;
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true) m = true;
    f1.Drawnewmap(m);

    f1.Show();//or ShowDialog()...
    this.Close();
}
```

Note that if the `Form2` is the main form "you can check about that at the Main", if you close it, it will exit the whole application, so if that is the case either make the form1 is the main form, or call this `this.Hide();` instead of `this.Close();`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to solve this problem using properties in the forms that hold a state

== *Form 1* ==

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool is_dsuzey;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (is_dsuzey) textBox1.Text = "1";
    }
    public bool IsDsuzey { get { return is_dsuzey; } set { is_dsuzey = value; } }

}
```

== *Form 2* ==

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.IsDsuzey = checkBox1.Checked;
        f1.Show();
    }
}
```

I would caution to put a `this.Close();` statement in `Form2` if it is the main form of the application because it will close out the entire application. If `Application.Run()` calls some other form, then there is no problem.